# How can we ever free ourselves from oil when government is so dependent on it?

Tags: united-states

Roughly 75% of all of the world's oil production is carried out by national oil companies: oil companies which are wholly or primarily run by government. At the same time, oil is traded in US dollars and that is one of the main things that is keeping the USD from collapsing. This explains why we have made so little progress in finding true alternatives to oil. So how are we going to let market forces take over?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18076/discussion-on-question-by-politicoid-how-can-we-ever-free-ourselves-from-oil-whe).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18121/discussion-between-politicoid-and-affable-geek).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem of oil, and fossil fuel in general, is not about the government. It's about engineering.

They say James Watt invented the steam engine; while this is true, he also based it on an earlier design that was just not quite good enough to reach mass adoption. In other words, he was the lucky one in a long chain of engineers who improved on earlier designs, all the way back to 13th century China where people started digging up coal when wood ran out.

The same thing is happening today with wind and solar; it works, but it's just not quite there where it could replace fossil fuels. Artificial photosynthesis would at least convert sunlight to hydrogen, which you can store, but that, too, will require lots and lots of further development until we have workable hydrogen cars that drive nicely and don't kill you. Then there's refilling stations...

Point being, the government isn't doing anything to stop new energy, on the contrary. Sure, the oil interests will put up a fight, but when the alternatives make enough money they get to lobby in Washington too. Google made enough money to start countering Hollywood and Big Telco, and SpaceX managed to get past Boeing. It's just a matter of time and determination.

As for the dollar falling upon obsolete oil, there are plenty of things that could happen. The Fed could just let it devalue, and lo and behold, hello domestic manufacturing and exports. (Less imports, but we're still the ones with the iPhones). The process of making free hydrogen might well be hard enough to keep secret for a while, which could lead to the oil trade simply picking it up and hence bolster the dollar.

Point being, the future is not bleak. The future is slow.

Comment: I would like to add that, regardless of the optimistic message, I regard it as a personal insult from the world to me that we don't have flying cars yet.

Comment: Crude oil is also used in the manufacture of many kinds of plastics, kerosine (jet fuel), and hundreds of other end products. This isn't just an **energy issue**.

Comment: @user1873 Yes, that's true! Which just means more engineering... hemp fiber mesh compounds, plant based medicine, titanium foil, the list of oil replacements that aren't quite there yet goes on and on.